# Is it possible to use Project API with with a single user installation?

Tags: eclipse-che

I would like to use Project API on top on Workspace API. I would like to test it on a docker installation single user.

The [documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/rest-api.html) seems to say Project API is secured. Shall I enable security for a single user, or shall I switch to multi-user setup?

I would have hoped to be able to remove security on all APIs in a single user mode

Comment: I found information here: https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/4117 and https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/4082

Answer (score 0):

Che in a single user mode does not have any auth checks, so, you can freely call services.